# Function type vs functions (methods)

Tags: swift, function

I was studying Swift when I came across this:

```
var action: () -> Void = {
    print "hi"
}   
var someVariable: Int -> Int
```

As I know so far that these should be function-type variables which "***action***" is a *"takes no parameters and returns nothing"*-type while "***someVariable***" is a *"takes an Int and returns an Int"*-type.

So my question is: Why not just use **func**?

```
func action() {
    print "hi"
}
func someVariable(a: Int) -> Int {
    return a + 1
}
```

Are these two the same thing? Or is there some preference when writing code to use **func** over function-type variables or vice-versa? If there is, when to use what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of:

```
var someVariable: Int -> Int
```

You're declaring a variable with a method signature accepting an Int and returning an Int.  You can assign any function that complies with this method signature.  You can pass this variable around and assign it like any other variable when necessary.  It adds flexibility as to how you can assign your methods.

Comment: So for example when another function takes a parameter I can pass "someVariable" into it since it is a "variable" while functions itself cannot be passed around?

Comment: Instead of creating another variable (var a = someVariable(1) ) simply to capture the return value of a function and pass it to another function?

Comment: @RayTso what Strat means is that you can assign *some* closure *to* `var someVariable` - for example you can write `someVariable = { a in return a * 2}` and later `someVariable = { a in return a * a}`. You cannot do the same thing with functions.

Comment: @RayTso Note that you can freely pass around both instance methods and function type variables. `let someFunction = someInstance.someInstanceMethod` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are a special case of Closures. As per the [Swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID95):

> Global functions are closures that have a name and do not capture any
> values.
>
> Nested functions are closures that have a name and can capture
> values from their enclosing function. Closure expressions are unnamed
> closures written in a lightweight syntax that can capture values from
> their surrounding context. Swift’s closure expressions have a clean,
> clear style, with optimizations that encourage brief, clutter-free
> syntax in common scenarios.

Being a special case of closures, functions can be used anywhere a closure is required.